# swift cannot add target to UIButton

Tags: ios, swift

so this question is super simple, but i checked that like a 100 times but it still won't work.

Basically, when user taps on tableView cell, it open another VC with different views, depending whether or not user is owner of post.
First condition, works just fine, adding target to button, while when second is being executed, nothing happens

```
lazy var buttonsView = DetailButtonsView() // those are almost the same
lazy var addvertView = AdvertiseView()
```

// inside of buttonsView()

```
lazy var skipButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("Пожаловаться", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.mainColor, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = .getPoppinsMediumFont(on: 15)

    return button
}()
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    setupView() //set up constraints
}
```

//inside of AdvertiseView()

```
    lazy var blackButton:UIButton = {
      var button = UIButton()
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 8
      button.backgroundColor = .black
      return button
  }()
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    setupView() //set up constraints 
}
```

//

```
 func setUpBottom() -> Void {

    if  dataInfo!.user_id! == UserSettings.userModel.id
    {
        self.backView.addSubview(addvertView) //also works

          addvertView.snp.makeConstraints //works
          {
              (make) in
              make.left.equalToSuperview()
              make.top.equalTo(userView.snp.bottom).offset(24)
              make.height.equalTo(450)
              make.bottom.lessThanOrEqualTo(-34)
          }


          addvertView.blackButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(blackButtonMethod), for: .touchUpInside) // does not add target 


    }
    else  {
        backView.addSubview(buttonsView) //works

        buttonsView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.left.right.equalToSuperview()
            make.top.equalTo(userView.snp.bottom).offset(24)
            make.bottom.lessThanOrEqualTo(-34)
        }
        buttonsView.skipButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toComplain), for: .touchUpInside) //works



    }

 @objc func toComplain(){ //works
    let vc = ComplaintTypeViewController()
    vc.advertID = dataInfo!.id!
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
@objc func blackButtonMethod(){ //does not work
    print("hello")
    parameters["action"] = "hot"
    parameters["advert_id"] = String(describing: dataInfo!.id)
    updateAdvert(parameters: parameters)
}
```

Comment: did you tried adding button.userInteractionEnabled = true?

Comment: yeah, but still nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target is probably added, but you cannot interact with it. That usually happens when constraints/frame is not set right. I see that the skip button uses:

```swift
button.setTitle("Пожаловаться", for: .normal)
```

which will infer autolayout width/height.

I don't see black blackButton's autolayout constraints or label set anywhere.

Comment: well, the button appears correctly, the way if should, cause i used contraints. i also added  title on button, and it appeared right in the middle of button. so that's not the case

Comment: then I suggest opening the button in the view hierarchy to examine whether its constraints and also its parent view's contstraints are right. Because if your parent for instance has 0 width/height, you might see the button displayed but it won't be touchable. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html

Comment: the whole thing did not work because i forgot to add right constraint.